# Writing a new file to a Google Cloud Storage bucket from a Google Cloud Function (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to write a new file (not upload an existing file) to a Google Cloud Storage bucket from inside a Python Google Cloud Function.

- I tried using [`google-cloud-storage`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/) but it does not have the
  "open" attribute for the bucket.
- I tried to use the App Engine library [`GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) but the function cannot   deploy with this dependencies.
- I tried to use [`gcs-client`](https://pypi.org/project/gcs-client/) but I cannot pass the credentials inside the function as it requires a `JSON` file.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your file locally and then to push it to GCS. You can't create a file dynamically in GCS by using open.

For this, you can write in the `/tmp` directory which is an in memory file system. By the way, you will never be able to create a file bigger than the amount of the memory allowed to your function minus the memory footprint of your code. With a function with 2Gb, you can expect a max file size of about 1.5Gb.

*Note: GCS is not a file system, and you don't have to use it like this*

---

**EDIT 1**

Things have changed since my answer:

- It's now possible to write in any directory in the container (not only the `/tmp`)
- You can stream write a file in GCS, as well as you receive it in streaming mode on CLoud Run. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59799941/writing-a-new-file-to-a-google-cloud-storage-bucket-from-a-google-cloud-function/70366028#70366028) a sample to stream write to GCS.

Note: stream write [deactivate the checksum validation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming-uploads#should-you-use). Therefore, you won't have integrity checks at the end of the file stream write.

Comment: How can I push it to GCS?

Comment: What are you talking about? Don't hesitate to create a new question if needed, it will be easier to share code and insights

Comment: Hello Guillaume, as you are accepted answer, it would be worthy to update it to the new fact that you can create file on GCS without uploading one. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70366028/1029722
Best regards

Comment: Thanks, I updated different part of my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
 from google.cloud import storage
 import io

 # bucket name
 bucket = "my_bucket_name"

 # Get the bucket that the file will be uploaded to.
 storage_client = storage.Client()
 bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket)

 # Create a new blob and upload the file's content.
 my_file = bucket.blob('media/teste_file01.txt')

 # create in memory file
 output = io.StringIO("This is a test \n")

 # upload from string
 my_file.upload_from_string(output.read(), content_type="text/plain")

 output.close()

 # list created files
 blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket)
 for blob in blobs:
     print(blob.name)

# Make the blob publicly viewable.
my_file.make_public()
```

Comment: Or just do this `my_file.upload_from_string("This is a test", content_type="text/plain")`

Answer (score 3):

You can now write files directly to Google Cloud Storage. It is no longer necessary to create a file locally and then upload it.

You can use the blob.open() as follows:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def write_file():
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-name')
    blob = bucket.blob('path/to/new-blob.txt')
    with blob.open(mode='w') as f:
        for line in object: 
            f.write(line)
```

You can find more examples and snippets here:
https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/tree/main/samples/snippets

Comment: Hi I use your answer and I need to get f BLOB filename. How to do it in Python please?