# How to download and store a file from web in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to use GCP to download a file from web and store it in the Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

For example, I need to download this file: https://gist.github.com/alwerner/5429504/archive/be5e2858bb31b37e0ba386ca2ce349bf0c3e20ef.zip

I've tried this code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70366028):

```
from google.cloud import storage

def write_file():
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-name')
    blob = bucket.blob('path/to/new-blob.txt')
    with blob.open(mode='w') as f:
        for line in object: 
            f.write(line)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to use it in case of web file.
How to download my file (by cloud function?) and store in the bucket on GCP?

Answer (score 1):

Get the file and write it doesn't work ?

```py
import requests

with requests.get("https://gist.github.com/alwerner/5429504/archive/be5e2858bb31b37e0ba386ca2ce349bf0c3e20ef.zip", stream=True) as response:
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-name')
    blob = bucket.blob('path/to/new-blob.txt')

    with blob.open(mode='wb') as f:
        for batch in response.iter_content(1024 * 1024 * 24): # 24 Mb batch
            f.write(batch)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib` or `requests` library to get the file from the url, then your existing python code to upload to Cloud Storage.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import urllib.request

project_id = 'your-project'
bucket_name = 'your-bucket'
destination_blob_name = 'upload.zip'
storage_client = storage.Client()

source_file_name = 'https://gist.github.com/alwerner/5429504/archive/be5e2858bb31b37e0ba386ca2ce349bf0c3e20ef.zip'

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    my_file = urllib.request.urlopen(source_file_name)

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_string(my_file.read(), content_type='application/zip')

upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name)
```